# Converting Bin-to-BCD code from VHDL to Verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog, hdl, conversion

Hello guys I am trying to translate following VHDL code to Verilog, however it does not work even if they look like pretty same. I get no errors however it is not working with Verilog one but works with VHDL one. Can you guys please help me to work out this problem?

VHDL Code (working)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity binbcd8 is

port(
b: in unsigned(7 downto 0);
p: out unsigned(9 downto 0)
);
end binbcd8;

architecture Behavioral of binbcd8 is

begin

bcd1: process(b)
variable z: unsigned(17 downto 0);
begin
for i in 0 to 17 loop
    z(i):='0';
end loop;

z(10 downto 3):=b;

for i in 0 to 4 loop
    if z(11 downto 8)>4 then
        z(11 downto 8):=z(11 downto 8)+3;
    end if;
    if z(15 downto 12)>4 then
        z(15 downto 12):=z(15 downto 12)+3;
    end if; 
    z(17 downto 1):=z(16 downto 0);
end loop;
p<=z(17 downto 8);

end process;    
end Behavioral;
```

Verilog code (not working):

```
 module binbcd8(input[7:0] b,output reg[9:0] p);
 reg[17:0] z;

 integer i;

 always@(b)
     begin
         z <=17'b0;
         z[10:3] <=b;
         for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1) begin
             if(z[11:8]>4)
                 z[11:8]<=z[11:8]+3;
             else
                 z<=z;
             if(z[15:12]>4)
                 z[15:12]<=z[15:12]+3;
             else
                 z<=z;
             z[17:1]<=z[16:0];
         end
         p<=z[17:8];
     end
 endmodule
```

It does not work. Can you please help me?:

Comment: Delete the non-standard `std_logic_unsigned` library. The `numeric_std` one should be adequate and avoids possible ambiguity. Also, the first `for` loop is unnecessary : `z := (others => '0');` replaces it with a single statement.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have no problem with vhdl my Problem is my verilog code is not working but vhdl is working by the way thanks for your advices

Comment: @NihadAzimli I've updated the question title to match you question - you had said Verilog to VHDL in the title, but are actually trying to go the other way.

Comment: Have you tried simulating the design? If so, can you describe what "it does not work" means. If you haven't simulated it, then you should do so.

Comment: Question also crossposted to SO and answered there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372347/vhdl-to-verilog-bintobcd-converting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable assigment in VHDL (with `:=`) takes place immediately. To get the same behaviour in Verilog, you have to use the blocking assignment with `=` instead of the non-blocking one (`<=`). In your example, blocking assigments for variable `z` are required because your code checks the new value of `z` immediately after assigning it.

Moreover, the loop runs from 0 to 4 (inclusive) in VHDL. In your Verilog code, it goes from 0 to 3 because it breaks out on 4. You have to change the condition in your `for` statement to "less or equal" comparison:

```
for(i=0; i<=4; i=i+1) begin
```

Minor code improvements:

After changing the assigment for `z` to a blocking one, you can remove these else-cases, because they have no effect:

```
    else
      z = z
```

In the addition, you should add a constant with a specific length:

```
      z[11:8] =z[11:8] +4'd3;
      z[15:12]=z[15:12]+4'd3;
```

The constant 3 without a length specification has a length of 32-bit and the synthesis compiler issues a warning about truncating to 4 bits.